# A questionable edit

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

I noticed that [my question has been edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55810305/revisions). However, the edit in question makes the question more annoying to read.

This edit consists of 3 parts:

1. Converting a name of a framework into code style - which does not make sense as names are not code;
2. Converting "which" into "that" - which is purely a word change without adding value to the question;
3. Converting "Number" to "The number" - which makes less sense as "Number" refers to the name of a property, and changing this word to "the number" loses this meaning.

Why are low-quality edits like these approved? Is this reputation farming by rapid-fire editing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; a conversation that was rapidly veering into unconstructive territory was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210782/discussion-on-question-by-happypig375-a-questionable-edit).

Comment: Grammatically speaking, the editor was correct in changing "which" to "that". The other edits were simply incorrect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The editor has enough reputation [to apply edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) without them having to go through the review queue.

If you disagree with the edit for whatever reason, you can just revert it by clicking the "rollback" button in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55810305/revisions), on the revision before the edit:

[image]